# Get Global Resource File from separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, resources

I would like to set button text with different languages based on Culture. I have all my Javascript code in separate file. This file is imported in ToolkitScriptManager in Master Page. I have created JSString.resx global resource file. I have written code:

```
function showSessionTime() {
    $(".sessionTime").val('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("JSString", "SessionTime").ToString() %>' + " " + convertTime(minutes) + ":" + convertTime(seconds)); seconds = seconds - 1;
}
```

The function is then called in $(document).ready(function ()...

The button in Master Page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all sessionTime"
                                        UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" 
                                        meta:resourcekey="Button2Resource1"></asp:Button>
```

I know that **<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("JSString", "SessionTime").ToString() %>** doesn't work in separate js files. How to workaround this as simple and as quick as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I check value like this:

```
   if ($("#ctl00_ddlLanguage").val() == 'pl-PL') {
        expiredMessage = 'Twoja sesja wygasła. Zostałeś wylogowany.';
    }
    else {
        expiredMessage = 'You session has ended. You have been logged out.';
    }
```

Is there any risk of using **#ctl00_ddlLanguage**??